# UIButton tapped getting [SecondPage performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: xcode

By using of Xcode 5 and auto-reference counting is enabled.

In a Non NavigationController based application i have take a UIButton and the IBAction and IBOutlet are properly defined and connected. But before the IBAction for TouchUpInside event called by Button taped the App gives "[SecondPage performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6cb7970". 
SecondPage is view-controller on which this UIButton exists.

Basically I want to open a new view-controller's view on this UIButton tapped and i will do this by Custom Segue

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Hmm strange it sounds like ARC is autoreleasing your secondView controller before your selector is being called.

Try defining your secondView as a property of the first (if you're adding it as a subview) with a property type of strong.

That's all I can recommend without seeing your code.

Comment: After adding the property with strong reference crash is not happening

Comment: @Matt Rees, this is what i assumed but i get this crash only on ios7 - Any thoughts?

Comment: @JoelBalmer iOS 7 won't make any difference, these methods have been around since iOS 5 and nothing has changed. The bug will be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: shame, as it's very similar, although it's actually "[firstViewController withObject: withObject:] message sent to deallocated instance"... balls, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same problem and solved with what Matt Rees suggested.

Just declair your     secondViewController in     firstViewController.h and made its instance there. Like,
    secondViewController *secondView;

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same problem and solved with what error thrown.

With more details, I was reallocating caller object (SecondPage in this case) on logout/login, but re-using some other viewcontrollers, so re-used viewcontroller have previous instance of caller object that I reallocated.

Well, solved it now!